# Can someone explain what Property Decorators in typescript are with a simple example?

Tags: typescript, properties, decorator

```
    function Log(target: any, propertyName: string|Symbol){
         console.log('Property decorator', target , propertyName);
    }

    class Product{
      @Log
      title:string;
      private _price: number;

      set price(val:number){
          if(val>0){
             this._price = val;
          }
          else{
             throw new Error('Invalid price');
          }
       }
      constructor(t:string, p:number){
             this.title = t;
             this._price = p;
     }
     getPriceWithTax(tax:number){
             return this._price*(1+tax);
     }
 }
```

This is returning Product: {},  "title". How to get back the constructor here? I do not understand. Am I not supposed to get back prototype here? What am I doing wrong in this case? I am trying to use a typescript property decorator.

Comment: If you google "ts decorators" you'll find a bunch of well written resources. For example [the official ts docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) or [this practical guide (that was at the top of the google search)](https://blog.logrocket.com/a-practical-guide-to-typescript-decorators/)

Comment: Kindly look at the example I provided. I cannot see the expected result. This left me confused.